# Getting 400 Bad Request on AJAX Call

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, ajax

I'm building a custom post type plugin using a class. I've got a form on a page which makes an AJAX call, and this returns a 400 Bad Request and a 0 response.

I've tried making the call independently of the page using Postman. Still the same response.

In constructor:

```
add_shortcode('websites_form', [$this, 'renderForm']);

// handle AJAX calls for both logged in and guest users
add_action('wp_action_websites_cpt_create_post', [$this, 'create_post']);
add_action('wp_action_nopriv_websites_cpt_create_post', [$this, 'create_post']);
```

The other two methods:

```
public function renderForm() {

    wp_register_script('websites-cpt-process-form', plugins_url('js/process-form.js', __FILE__), null, null, true );

    // vars being sent to JS
    $php_vars = [
        // passing the url to call for passing the form data back to WP
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) ? 'https://' : 'http://' )
    ];
    wp_localize_script( 'websites-cpt-process-form', 'phpvars', $php_vars );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'websites-cpt-process-form' );


    return file_get_contents( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "partials/websites-form.php" );
}

public function create_post() {
    global $oLog;

    $oLog->logrow('POST', $_POST);

    // verify nonce

    // create post with name in title

    // add url in metadata

    // echo response
    echo json_encode($_POST);

    // die
    die();
}
```

So it looks like the `wp_action-XXX` actions aren't getting registered. I tried putting `echo`'s and such in the `create_post()` method, but nothing showed up in the output.

Any suggestions appreciated. I'm not sure where to turn to next.

Comment: Do you instantiate the class? It's hard to tell without seeing the whole code.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure. I understand. Always worth asking obvious questions. You never know. @Sally figured it out: I was hooking `wp_action_XXX` instead of `wp_ajax_XXX`. d'Oh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
// handle AJAX calls for both logged in and guest users
add_action('wp_action_websites_cpt_create_post', [$this, 'create_post']);
add_action('wp_action_nopriv_websites_cpt_create_post', [$this, 'create_post']);
```

Because the format should be:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_{ACTION_NAME}', [ $this, 'create_post' ] );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_{ACTION_NAME}', [ $this, 'create_post' ] );
```

..where `{ACTION_NAME}` is the "action" name, e.g. *websites_cpt_create_post*.

See [`wp_ajax_{$_REQUEST['action']}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax__requestaction/) and [`wp_ajax_nopriv_{$_REQUEST['action']}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv__requestaction/).